# Subquery to String?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table containing countries:

```
id     country
------------
0     Monaco 
1     Mongolia
2     Montenegro
3     Morocco
4     Mozambique
5     Myanmar
```

I have a sub query that looks like this.

```
(SELECT country FROM COUNTRIES WHERE id < 10) AS ´Trip´
```

I want to have that subquery to be formatted as a string like this:

`'Monaco, Mongolia, Montenegro, Morocco, Mozambique, Myanmar'`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT group_concat(country, ', ') FROM countries WHERE id < 10
```

Comment: FYI It appears the comma is added by default... your above solution will result (monaco,,mongolia,,motengegro...);  Other than that, perfect solution.

Comment: use just group_concat(country) to get monaco,mongolia...) result

Answer (score 2):

What Lukas said, but use the SEPARATOR for your ,'s

```
SELECT group_concat(country SEPARATOR ', ') FROM countries WHERE id < 10
```

This is useful if you want a ';' instead of a ','